# Is statistical significance of a regressor important in forecasting different scenarios?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, forecasting, arima

I have a good regression with ARMA errors (with exogenous variables), and it gives me reasonable forecasts. But now I need to construct different scenarios to forecast. My question is: Should I worry about the p-values of my regressors("x")? **I dont care about the specific relationship between "y" and "x"**. But I want to know if its still valid to forecast different scenarios for "x", if my "x" are not significant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "non-significant" regressors in the same way you use the significant ones. After all, significance is just an arbitrary choice.

What "non-significance" means is that maybe you should consider removing that variable from the model and still keep or even improve predictive power

Answer (score 0):

Many times the goal is to achieve prediction accuracy rather than finding the impact of an individual predictor on the response or model interpretability.

Depending upon the domain and objective of the research/project, you need to decide what's more important in your case.

Usually in forecasting variable significance is not that important, if you're getting better forecasts.

Refer: http://andreykostenko.com/publications/sst2.pdf